# Check whether string is jinja2 Template or not

Tags: python, string, templates, jinja2

I am trying to execute the below code of jinja2 in python. Here value could be any string either it will contain jinja syntax or it will be just a normal string. It is working fine if I am using Jinja syntax in the specified string but when I am trying to specify the normal string then it is throwing error something like this ***TypeError: Can't compile non template nodes***

```
value = Template(value)
value = value.render(self.__user_defined_vars.user_vars)
```

Is there any way to check whether that string is jinja template or just a normal string?

Comment: why not handle the error instead of checking the string?

Comment: Handling the error directly is not always a good practice. right? If I can check with something like isinstance function then it will be more beneficial and clean code that handling the error itself

Comment: well, here we disagree

Comment: Also can you post [mre] and full traceback you get?

Answer (score 0):

> You often hear that Python encourages EAFP style ("it's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission") over LBYL style ("look before you leap")

or simply code below which works for most cases

```py
def is_jinja(s):
    return re.search('{{.+}}',s) or re.search('{%.+%}',s)
```